# htmlwidgets and shiny apps can't be viewed on E-Books Output formats in bookdown

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, bookdown

At this moment is not possible to see neither htmlwidgets nor shiny apps on E-Books output formats in bookdown. Even if I download the example: [bookdown: Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/), I am not be able to see a screenshot as it promises. Large parts of bookdown's chapters are not available to see on these formats. e.g.   Some idea?

Comment: The link you shared points to the book, not a specific example. Try to include minimal example in your post instead of an external link.

Comment: If you download that book in EPUB, you can see that neither 2.10 and 2.11 numerals nor some others can not be seen in the digital book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is indeed a screenshot of the shiny app.

[image]

Maybe you need to use a right application to open the `.epub` file, such as **SumatraPDF** on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @gitzhuoer.

Comment: It's so kind of you to mark my answer as "accepted". Would you please vote it up? @Martin Andres Macias Quintero